# Discrete Math Proof: $A \cup B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm preparing ahead for a Discrete Math course coming up this year by doing some practice problems supplemented by online notes.

The problem I'm having trouble proving is the following:

$A \cup B = (A \cap B^C) \cup (A^C \cap B) \cup (A \cap B)$, where $^C$ denotes complement of a set

I know I should use some of the Laws of the algebra of sets, but this is all so new that it's difficult for me to conceptualize which law to begin with.

UPDATE:

For any two finite sets A and B: $A \cup B = (A\B) \cup B$

$Using: (X\Y) = (X \cap Y^C)$

I found that:

$A \cup B = (A \cap B^C) \cup B$, substituting for A

$A \cup B = (A \cap B^C) \cup (B \cap A^C)$, substituting for A and B

SECOND UPDATE:

After gaining insight from everyone I've figured it out (or so I hope).

$A \cup B = (A \cap B^C) \cup (A^C \cap B) \cup (A \cap B)$

Rearrange using Commutative laws:

$(A \cap B^C) \cup (A \cap B) \cup (A^C \cap B)$

Applying the Distributive laws we get:

$(A \cap (B^C \cup B)) \cup (A^C \cap B)$

Then by Complement laws:

$A \cap U \cup (A^C \cap B)$

Using the Identity laws:

$A \cup (A^C \cap B)$

Using the Distributive laws:

$(A \cup A^C) \cap (A \cup B)$

By Complement laws:

$U \cap (A \cup B)$

Finally, using Identity laws we get:

$A \cup B$

Comment: Note that $B = (B \cap A) \cup (B \cap A^C)$. Thus, $A \cup B = (A \cap B^C) \cup B = (A \cap B^C) \cup (A^C \cap B) \cup (A \cap B)$.

Comment: Awesome, this helped! I've re-written my proof if you would like to have a look at it.

Comment: Nice work.  The work you did on the right hand side of the equation to transform $(A \cap B^C) \cup (A^C \cup B) \cup (A \cap B)$ into $A \cup B$ is your proof, you do not need the left hand side of each equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively the result says that if an element is in $A \cup B$, then either the element is in $A$ and not $B$, $B$ and not $A$, or in both $A$ and $B$.

The arguement can then proceed as follows:

$\begin{array}{l l} x \in A \cup B & \Leftrightarrow x \in A \text{ and } x \not\in B \text{, or } x \not\in A \text{ and } x \in B \text{, or } x \in A \text{ and } x \in B\\  & \Leftrightarrow  x \in (A \cap B^c)\cup(A^c \cap B)\cup(A \cap B) \end{array}$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand your method of proving; however, would you have any insight as to how to prove it with the Laws of the algebra of sets?

Comment: @brto  Show that if $x \in A \cup B$, then $x \in (A \cap B^C) \cup (A^C \cap B) \cup (A \cap B)$, then show the opposite inclusion.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Okay. Does the "UPDATE" in my original post follow?

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First, you should not begin your proof by stating what you intend to prove. Instead of starting by writing $A \cup B = (A \cap B^C) \cup (A^C \cap B) \cup (A \cap B)$ and aiming to reach $A\cup B = A\cup B$, you should start with $(A \cap B^C) \cup (A^C \cap B) \cup (A \cap B)$ and show that it equals (through rewriting it in various forms that are the same set) as $A\cup B$.

(You can also show that two sets are equal by showing that each is a subset of the other; I don’t mean that my suggestion is the only approach, but it’s the appropriate way to write the proof using the particular mathematical argument you are presenting.)

This may seem like a silly question of style, but the fact is that you have only explained that *if* what you want to prove happens to be true, then it must follow that $A\cup B = A\cup B$. This is not a proof. It would also follows that $A\cup B = A\cup B$ even if what you began with is false. Any assumptions, even false ones, logically imply a true statement. A conjecture is not proven true by showing that you can use it to conclude a true statement. You have to show that you can proceed logically from true statements to prove *it*.

Second, you should add some parentheses. At one point (after you use the distributive law), you write the expression $ A \cap (B^C \cup B) \cup (A^C \cap B)$. You intend for this to mean $\left(A \cap (B^C \cup B)\right) \cup (A^C \cap B)$, and it’s safest to say so, because combinations of $\cup$ and $\cap$ may give different results depending on the order in which the operators are evaluated.

Comment: Great suggestions. Although my intentions were to prove $A \cup B=(A \cap B^C) \cup (A^C \cap B)∪(A \cap B)$, but I can see how my implementation shows otherwise.